# GTK+ Replace gdk_draw_pixbuf with Cairo

Tags: c, gtk, cairo, gdkpixbuf

I'm working on a GtkDrawingArea which, in the expose event, is drawing a section of a pixbuf in a tiled manner. The tiling type varies - depending on the source image; it can be orthogonal, isometric or hexagonal. Drawing this with gdk_draw_pixmap is simple enough; here is an example on how it looks for isometric tiling:

```
for(y=0,row=0; y+tile_height<height; y+=tile_half_height,++row)
  for(x=((row&1)? tile_half_width : 0); x+tile_width<width; x+=tile_width)
    gdk_draw_pixbuf(widget->window,NULL,
                    pixbuf,src_x,src_y,
                    x,y,tile_width,tile_height,
                    GDK_RGB_DITHER_NONE,0,0);
```

Result:

[image: Isometric tiling with gdk_draw_pixbuf]

However, drawing the same with Cairo proved to be quite not the same. This is what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr,pixbuf,src_x,src_y);
for(y=0,row=0; y+tile_height<height; y+=tile_half_height,++row)
  for(x=((row&1)? tile_half_width : 0); x+tile_width<width; x+=tile_width) {
    cairo_rectangle(cr,x,y,tile_width,tile_height);
    cairo_paint(cr);
  }
}
cairo_destroy(cr);
```

Result:

[image: Isometric tiling with Cairo]

Cairo simply refuses to draw the image as a normal raster image would be drawn. What am I doing wrong, how is this solved?

Comment: [`cairo_paint()` fills the clip region, not the current path](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-paint); you will need to convert the path you created with `cairo_rectangle()` into a clip region with `cairo_clip()`. (Remember that the clip region is preserved over time, so you will also need `cairo_save()` and `cairo_restore()` in your for loop.)

Comment: I don't know how `cairo_fill` handles image sources; you could try that. I've only ever used it with solid colors.

Comment: Nope, same result. The problem is that the entire source image is used as the pattern, even when I only want to use a section of it. I need to fix src_x, src_y, which isn't happening in Cairo - src_x, src_y is simply the starting point in the source image, then it adjusts in the source image by x, y accordingly.

Comment: I've also tried combinations of `cairo_translate()`, but it seems trial and error amounts to infinity in this case, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but might work. If not, then report back and I'll try again:

```
static void _cairo_gdk_draw_pixbuf(cairo_t *cr, cairo_surface_t *source,
        int src_x, int src_y,
        int dest_x, int dest_y,
        int width, int height)
{
    cairo_save(cr);

    /* Move (0, 0) to the destination position */
    cairo_translate(cr, dest_x, dest_y);

    /* Set up the source surface in such a way that (src_x, src_y) maps to
     * (0, 0) in user coordinates. */
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, source, -src_x, -src_y);

    /* Do the drawing */
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, width, height);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    /* Undo all of our modifications to the drawing state */
    cairo_restore(cr);
}
```

The above function should work like `gdk_draw_pixbuf` (well, similar to it).